# Inconsistency between database and Django ORM output at breakpoint

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, pdb

While debugging a unit test in Django, I placed the following statement in my code

```
Student.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2]).delete()
...
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

At the breakpoint, if I type `Student.objects.count()`, I can see that it has reduced due to delete however if I open `psql` (PostgreSQL command line) and check the `test_database`, I can still see the rows (which have been deleted according to Django). Why do I see this inconsistency between Django ORM & the database. Does the ORM cache my queries? How can I make it commit to the database at the breakpoint?

**Update**:

Quick solution for debugging. Add the following lines at breakpoint to see the data in `psql`. Thanks to @DanielRoseman for the tip.

```
    from django.db import connection
    connection.cursor().execute('commit;')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django requests usually run inside a transaction. Your psql session won't see the changes until the transaction is committed when the session returns.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Makes sense after reading up a bit on transactions. Otherwise, it was baffling for someone not familiar with the inner workings.